# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar todas las filas de la tabla en mi aplicación de Google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

mi problema es el siguiente, al filtrar en la aplicación de GAS ingresando el código de persona como parámetro, solo me filtra la primera fila encontrada  en mi hoja de calculo de Google, no se como hacer para me filtre las demás filas con el mismo código.

Esto es la estructura básica para hacer una aplicación en linea  donde las personas puedan consultar sus estados de cuenta el cual va a estar guardado en una hoja de calculo con una estructura mas desarrollada, lo que me impide terminarlo es lo que ya comente arriba, que solo filtra la primera fila encontrada y a las demás no, a continuación facilito mis documentos:

[HOJA DE CALCULO](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EHthjPbhQUOEHVVd_xCcrx7g1N0Wki8A_2ndeGihHGU/edit#gid=0)

[APLICACION EN EJECUCION](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxFqmi4-7z0YI3PomUH0eXJVPw-yT1XJInckcJq/exec?CODIGO=8)

Mi código GAS es el siguiente:

```
 function doGet(e) {


  // CONECCION A LA HOJA

  // Parámetros de acceso a la hoja de datos  
  var idLibro = '1EHthjPbhQUOEHVVd_xCcrx7g1N0Wki8A_2ndeGihHGU'
  var nombreHoja = 'A';
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idLibro).getSheetByName(nombreHoja);

    // Parámetros de la tabla de resultados

    var filResultados = 3; // A partir de qué fila se encuentran los                   
     resultados en la tabla
    var colcod = 1;
    var colnombre = 2;
    var colapellido = 3;
    var colmonto = 4;  

      // Obtener CODIGO
    
      var codigo = e.parameter.CODIGO;
    
      if (codigo != '' && codigo != null) {
  
        // Vamos a buscar al deudor
        
        filaRes = filResultados;
  while (filaRes <= hoja.getLastRow() && String(hoja.getRange(filaRes,             
 colcod).getValue()).toUpperCase() != codigo.toUpperCase()) {filaRes++;}
  
        if (filaRes > hoja.getLastRow()) {   
    
          // CODIGO no está en la tabla
    
          var plantillaHtml = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('error');
          plantillaHtml.mensaje = 'Codigo no encontrado';
          return plantillaHtml.evaluate().setTitle('TEST CONSULTA FILAS');
        }
        else {
          
          // CODIGO SI ESTA EN LA TABLA
            
            var plantillaHtml =             HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('resultados');
            plantillaHtml.codigo = codigo;
            plantillaHtml.nnombres= hoja.getRange(filaRes,       colnombre).getDisplayValue();
            plantillaHtml.napellidos = hoja.getRange(filaRes,       colapellido).getDisplayValue();
            plantillaHtml.nanhual = hoja.getRange(filaRes, colmonto).getDisplayValue();
            // Devolver página HTML con resultados vía scriptlets
            return plantillaHtml.evaluate().setTitle('TEST CONSULTA       FILAS');        
        }
      }
      else {
  
        // Faltan parámetros
  
        var plantillaHtml = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('error');
        plantillaHtml.mensaje = 'Faltan datos de autenticación';
        return plantillaHtml.evaluate().setTitle('TEST CONSULTA FILAS');    
      }

  }
```

Y mi código HTML es el siguiente:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
     <style type="text/css">
     .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-width:1px;border-     style:solid;border-color:#999;}
     .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px      5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-     color:#999;color:#444;background-color:#F7FDFA;}
     .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-     weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-     width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-     color:#999;color:#fff;background-color:#26ADE4;}
     .tg .tg-lvva{font-weight:bold;background-color:#0c1a78;text-     align:center}
     .tg .tg-tzx7{background-color:#0c1a78;text-align:center}
     .tg .tg-5hgy{background-color:#D2E4FC;text-align:center}
     .tg .tg-44gf{background-color:#D2E4FC;font-weight:bold;font-size:x-     large;border-color:#0c1a78;text-align:center}
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div style="text-align:center">
     <img      src="https://cdn.bitrix24.com/b9316961/landing/027/027c19d37fefaaa64fc64510f40c2e     60/Selecci_n_567.png">
     <h1>TEST CONSULTA FILAS</h1>
     <table style="margin: 0px auto" class="tg">
     <tr>
     <th class="tg-tzx7">Nombres</th>
     <th class="tg-tzx7">Apellidos</th>
     <th class="tg-tzx7">Anual</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td class="tg-5hgy"><?= nnombres ?></td>
     <td class="tg-5hgy"><?= napellidos ?></td>
     <td class="tg-5hgy"><?= nanhual?></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    Deudas para la persona con codigo: <b><?= codigo.toUpperCase() ?></b>
     <br><br>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [so]. Agrega un [mcve]

Comment: Por cierto, no se recomienda usar métodos de `SpreadsheetApp` en bucles porque son muy lentos. Usa `hoja.getDataRange(),getValues()` para en una llamada leer todos los valores de la hoja, luego usa métodos de Array así harás tu código mucho más eficiente.